path based routing in geolocation routing
I have one web application example.com which is hosted in an EC2 server(AWS). One server is hosted in the London region and another in the Mumbai region. I am using a global accelerator for geolocation routing(standard routing). So the user is connecting to the nearest server. But I need to use a VPN if I want to connect to my London server. but I need some path-based routing. For instance, the domain example.com/uk needs to route the London server, and the domain example.com/in needs to route the Mumbai server. Is there any good solution for this?
Architecture: Global accelerator points to two endpoints, Mumbai and London ALB. IP of the global accelerator is added to Route53.
I have checked different configurations of the global accelerator and ALB. Nothing works
